# I <verb> and am <rest of sentence>

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, coordinating-conjunctions, conjunction-reduction

I sometimes find myself writing something like this:

> XXX is a project I admire and am very interested in.

The "I <verb> and am <something>" feels strange here. It somehow sounds more natural in the third person: "He admires and is very interested in...."

Am I just imagining things – is it OK to use this construction, or should I use something completely different?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

This sentence is an example of ***Conjunction Reduction***, the syntactic rule that deletes repeated material in conjoined constituents, for example

- *Bill washed the dishes and **Bill** swept the floor.* ➝
  *Bill washed the dishes and swept the floor.*
- *Bill washed the dishes and **Bill** dried **the dishes**.* ➝
  *Bill washed and dried the dishes.*

The relative clause modifying *project* in the original sentence is the focus, so let's get it out of a subordinate clause and see what it looks like:

- *I admire and am very interested in the project.*

which comes from

- *I admire **the project** and **I** am very interested in the project.*

by a perfectly normal application of Conjunction Reduction.

There's nothing grammatically wrong with this sentence.

One thing that may make it feel wrong to some -- but not others; there's a lot of individual variation here, since everybody makes up their own internal rules, for their own reasons, about what "sounds right" -- is that the first verb of the conjoined VP (*admire*) is uninflected for person and number, while the second verb (*am*) **is** inflected, for first person singular present tense.

Both verbs agree of course with the same subject, but morphologically instead of syntactically, which may produce some distress to those who require more grammatical parallelism between conjoined verbs.

Another related difficulty might be that the inflected form *am* is so closely linked to its subject pronoun *I* that it is difficult to separate them, and indeed most of the time they're contracted to *I'm*. This makes *am* feel rather isolated out there.

Again, this isn't a grammatical problem *per se*, but it can occasion some distress in some readers.

I say "*readers*" because nobody would **say** such a sentence, of course. We'd say *I'm* instead of *am*, by repeating the subject -- and adding no new syllables, so timing isn't affected. This is allowed syntactically because Conjunction Reduction is an optional rule applied to reduce unwelcome repetition, and in any given case this repetition may simply not be unwelcome.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Indeed, my lack of comfort with this sentence is the "isolation" of "am".

Comment: Isn't the issue rather that *admire* has a direct object, whereas *am very interested in* has a prepositional object? A zeugma or "conjunction reduction" can work with that in simple sentences, but the combination of (1.) different kinds of objects and (2.) some distance between the first verb and its object can be off-putting.

Comment: @Cerberus: I don't think that's a problem; English has lots of phrasal verbs, and mixing them in parallel constructions is generally permissible. e.g. "(cease) and (desist from) doing somthing".

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail: Yes, generally; but there is little distance between *cease* and *desist from*. And *cease and desist* is a very familiar fixed pair. I think mixing different kinds of objects can become a bit of an issue in a construction like this when there is some distance between the two: *this man I fear but defer to* v. *this man I fear but would gladly serve* v. *this man I fear but would gladly defer to*. Somehow the last sentence is a bit less easy on the tongue than the first two.

Comment: Greg Lee insists that " 'I admire and am very interested in the project.'
which comes from

'I admire the project and I am very interested in the project.'
by a perfectly normal application of Conjunction Reduction." is incorrect. Is this the usual different-terminology issue?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: You'd have to ask Greg about that. He may be right, but i don't aim for pinpoint accuracy in terminology here in ELU; there are few linguists here and our disagreements are mostly irrelevant in this context.

Comment: I had not met John when he wrote that “nobody would **say** such a sentence, of course.”  When next we meet, I hope I'll find occasion to do so, heh heh.

Answer (score 16):

Not only do I agree that it is grammatically correct, but I don't think it sounds strange or unusual either.

However, the beauty of the English language is that there are usually a dozen different ways of communicating the same things, so if you aren't comfortable with it, by all means use something else.

Answer (score 10):

Grammatically there is nothing wrong with it. *And* coordinates two of the same type of phrase; *am* and *admire* are verbs, so you're just coordinating two verb phrases:

> XXX is a project I [[admire] and [am very interested in]].

If the final preposition is making it feel awkward, you could try *XXX is a project I admire and in which I'm very interested.*

Comment: I think probably OP feels the construction is a little awkward because *two different elements* are being elided - "that" (or "which", the project), as well as "I". Personally I agree it might be a step too far in writing, but it's fine in informal speech.

Comment: I agree that the trailing preposition is the only troublesome part of the example.

Comment: I like most of this answer, but I think the trailing preposition is fine.  The proposed alternative is, in contrast, fairly awkward.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Funny, I would say the exact opposite: it’s fine in writing, but I would never dream of saying it in informal speech, and anyone who did would risk coming off a bit poncy-posh. Colloquially, I would always repeat the subordinator and the pronoun: “XXX is a project I admire and that I’m very interested in”. On the other hand (to alcas and Ben’s point), I would never move up the preposition unless deliberately going for a _very_ formal feel. I agree with snailboat that “… and in which I’m very interested” is awfully clunky and unnatural to me.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's technically wrong, but I share your view that it sounds a bit strange.

How about:

> Etherpad is a project that has been attracting my interest and
>   admiration for a long time.

instead?

Answer (score 0):

It is grammatically correct but it sounds like an "effect" to me, or like a zeugma. These rhetorical effects are better used in a proper context, maybe poetry, maybe humorous, or to attract the attention of the reader on the presence of your sentence. Here it is not the case: you want to attract the attention of the reader to the subject ("XXX"), not to your writing.

Answer (score -3):

If you tweak the structure of your sentence, you can change its rhythm. 

Try adding a pronoun to the original to form a compound sentence ...

like this ...

> XXX is a project I admire, and I am very interested in it.

or this ...

> I admire XXX, and I am very interested in it.

or this ...

> XXX is a project I admire, and it holds my interest.