# A and B + noun or nouns?

Tags: grammatical-number, conjunctions

As the title, I am not sure of it.

For example,

> Can you see the blue and red cup / the blue and red cups?

Assuming there is one blue and one red cup.

Thanks!

Comment: The title is a little bit ambiguous to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When phrases with the same words are combined by "and"/"or"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52284/when-phrases-with-the-same-words-are-combined-by-and-or)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is just based on my personal understanding. I think if you have one blue and one red cup, it is better to say:

> Can you see the blue and the red cup?

This adds more emphasis and makes the reader understand that the cup is not "blue and red."

Similarly, for the plural form, I would say:

> Can you see the blue and the red cups?