# Is " ... and was wondering ..." correct?

Tags: subjects

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I <verb> and am <rest of sentence>](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51930/i-verb-and-am-rest-of-sentence)

Since I'm a native Spanish speaker I tend to suppress the subject a lot when speaking, since most of the time it's tacit for us.

So, many times I find myself writing things like *"but I'm not sure, and was wondering"*, which sounds good to me, but then I realize that, in this case, *was* doesn't have a corresponding subject, at least not an immediate one.

Can the subject (I) from the first part of the sentence be considered as the subject of the remaining statement ("was wondering")? I guess not, but it doesn't hurt to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can apply the subject of the sentence to multiple predicates, e.g.:

> I found a seat, curled up, and began to read my book.
>
> I think so, but I'm not sure, and was wondering that myself.

Comment: Yet more [Conjunction Reduction](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51930/i-verb-and-am-rest-of-sentence/51955#51955). This is the third or fourth time in the last couple of days this has come up.

Comment: This is a form of ellipsis, yes?