# Single Preposition/descriptor for Multiple Subjects versus Multiple Ones

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, conjunction-reduction

Could anybody please tell which one is correct?

> The President is going to give speeches **in** Belgium, **in**
>   the Netherlands, **in** Luxembourg and **in** France

versus

> The President is going to give speeches **in** Belgium, the Netherlands,
>   Luxembourg and France

Comment: See also Oxford, or serial comma.

Comment: Example of what happens when serial comma is omitted: "The President is going to give speeches in Belgium, Netherlands, Serbia and Montenegro and France."

Comment: The comma is irrelevant; insert it if you hear it, otherwise don't. The omission of prepositions, on the other hand, is syntactic and licensed by the syntactic rule of [Conjunction Reduction](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/78109/15299).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are fine.  The second is an example of a rhetorical device called "zeugma," in which one word applies to many in a set of parallel constructions.  Here you have a set of countries that are all the objects in a prepositional phrase, but the preposition appears only once.

Comment: I am not sure the second is an example of Zeugma. [[ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma ]] If it had been " ... give speeches in Belgium, English, & Parliament ... ", then the 3 items are not part of a list and may be considered Zeugma.

Comment: I'll plead *The Concise Oxford Dictionary of Literary Terms*.  There are many types of zeugma.  You've picked one in which the preposition governs different objects in different ways.  You could even say "he will give a speech in English and humility," combining a literal and a figurative use.

Comment: I checked few more resources and am even more convinced that the second is not an example of Zeugma. [[ http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/zeugma : the use of a word to modify or govern two or more words when it is **appropriate to only one** of them or is **appropriate to each but in a different way**, as in "to wage war and peace" or "On his fishing trip, he caught three trout and a cold" ]] Here "in X, Y, & Z" is a simple list, and "in" means the same for all the items and is the same as "in X, in Y & in Z".

Comment: @Prem You've found a particular type of zeugma called "syllepsis" according to the classifications of *CODoLT*.   If you'd prefer to go with an online dictionary, be my guest.

Comment: Do you have a web reference where there is an example of Zeugma matching your Definition ? Do you have any online material in your support ? I have seen many (and provided two) references where the Definition used is as per my previous comment. { I do not want to start arguing , I only want to learn more }

Comment: @Prem The [Wikipedia article on zeugma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma) includes the CODLT usage (as one of four partly conflicting definitions). I'm not sure if this makes it unsound (being online), but OED and most if not all of Macauley are available online, so perhaps that argument is specious. What I'm more concerned about is the niche usage without a sensible caveat.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth , I agree with you on the concerns about "the niche usage without a sensible caveat".

Answer (score 0):

**Both forms are correct.**

"... in X, in Y, in Z ..." : **Multiple IN form** is used in two cases:
(A) when somebody wants to emphasis some words. Eg "... **in** Belgium, **in** Nederlands, ...".
(B) when somebody is speaking impromptu, and wants time to think between countries. Eg "Well, I know the president will give speeches in Belgium, ... in Nederlands, ... in Luxembourg and .... in France".

"... in X, Y, Z ..." **Single IN form** is nice&short.

Informational Comment:
When some items require Different Prepositional words ("about", "of", "for", "on", "with", etc), we may see many uses of "in" in the same sentence. Eg. "I write stories **in** weekly magazines **about** hunting **in** Africa, **for** American audiences "with" an interest **in** wildlife".

Answer (score 0):

Oxford comma aside, the choice is purely rhetorical, stylistic, rhythmic -- it all depends on how it sounds to you.  Do you read your work out loud?  That can help you decide.  Including the "ins" is more emphatic, to my ear;  it highlights the fact that the President is giving a number of speeches and that they are in different countries.  But it's all up to you, how you want it to sound.