# Can I omit the preposition "to" in front of every ing-form verb in a series connected by "and"?

Tags: phrase-usage, conjunction-reduction

Given this sentence:

> I look forward to learning new subjects and contributing to teaching them, (to?) facing new and diverse challenges, and (to?) producing outstanding work.

My instinct is that I can omit the second and third *to*, but can someone please confirm and explain?

Comment: Yes, you can do it, but stylistically it can make your writing more difficult to read.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Single Preposition/descriptor for Multiple Subjects versus Multiple Ones](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/259055/single-preposition-descriptor-for-multiple-subjects-versus-multiple-ones)

Comment: Does that matter if there's not a satisfactory answer to the "original"? That aside, is it strange that I think SCinSF's sentence should begin, "I look forward to learning new subjects and *to* contributing to teaching them..." (although I think "contributing to teaching them" is an oddly worded phrase and idea)?

Comment: The inclusion of the 3rd and 4th _to_'s introduces an ambiguity (context disambiguates here, but it's still clumsy, garden-pathy). Omitting them introduces a different ambiguity. _Have they been omitted?_  (I used to look forward to standing in the Stretford End, watching United, and eating a hot dog.)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I edited the sentence as follows: "I look forward to learning new subjects, contributing to teach them, and producing outstanding work."

Answer (score 2):

The problem here lies in the depth and complexity of ideas. In your enthusiasm to impress you get unnecessarily complex. Isolating an example:

I (1) look forward (2) to contributing (3) to teaching them.

You could simplify by getting rid of level 2, which adds little to your meaning. The isolated example becomes:

I (1) look forward (2) to teaching [new subjects].

That already sounds much better. How will the whole thing sound with this change?

I look forward to learning new subjects, teaching them, facing new and diverse challenges, and producing outstanding work.

Leaner and meaner.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can omit the extra instances of *to*.  Here's an example sentence:

> I'm looking forward to going whitewater rafting, climbing a mountain, running a marathon and hiking the Appalachian Trail from one end to the other.

If I had used *to* for every single verb, it would sound tedious and stuffy.