# stated rule on use of infinitives in a sequence?

Tags: infinitives

Is there a stated rule on use of infinitives in a sequence? Or is it a question of style?  For example,

> It is vital for a viewer of this movie **to listen** for its main character's underlying position, **to contrast** it with those of the other characters, and ultimately **to determine** which view is true.

Comment: Isn't it simply a matter of putting them in a logical sequence. One can't "determine" before one has "contrasted" and one cannot "contrast" before one has "listened" - not in that example anyway.

Comment: Rule concerning what specifically?

Comment: Are you asking about the "rule, syntactic principle" that allows us to "delete" the infinitive marker ***to*** from the second and third highlighted infinitives? It's entirely a stylistic choice whether to explicitly repeat ***to*** in this context, and you can either delete *both* (2nd & 3rd) or *neither*, or (at a pinch) just delete the *last* one. But idiomatically you ***can't*** delete only the second instance, and "resurrect" it for the final one.

Comment: Another example of [Conjunction Reduction](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/78109/15299), which links the example sentence with a compound sentence _It is vital for a viewer of this movie to listen for its main character's underlying position, it is vital for a viewer of this movie to contrast it with those of the other characters, and ultimately it is vital for a viewer of this movie to determine which view is true._ Conjunction Reduction removes repeated material -- but it has to be repeated **exactly** the same. And it doesn't just apply to infinitives; it's **much** more general.

Answer (score 2):

In a series, one word will often refer to all the items in the series. Consider this sentence:
"The knight had strong armour, shield, and lance." Strong refers to all three equally.

"It is vital for a viewer of this movie to listen for its main character's underlying position, contrast it with those of the other characters, and ultimately determine which view is true."

In your sentence, removing the second and third "to" while not incorrect, makes it more difficult for the reader to pick up the beginning of each listed item. Especially because each item is complex.  So repeating the "to" when using infinitives in a complex series makes the sentence clearer. [300 Days to better writing](https://300daysofbetterwriting.wordpress.com/2014/02/04/repeat-to-when-using-infinitives-in-a-complex-series/)

Comment: Never mind repeating just ***to*** in OP's context. It would be *syntactically* valid to repeat any of ***it is vital for a viewer of this movie, vital for a viewer of this movie,*** or ***for a viewer of this movie*** - and probably other "reduced" versions of the implicitly repeated initial clause.

Comment: True. Probably wouldn't make it clearer though.

Comment: Hmm. I find it easy enough to imagine a public speaker bombastically repeating the entire initial clause ***It is vital for a viewer of this movie to...*** before ***each*** of the required actions, and it's pretty obvious to me that this would make the entire statement much clearer and more impactful to even the most inattentive members of his audience. And in fact I see now that John Lawler has made much the same assertion in a comment under the question.