# "Either your dog or your cat eats" vs. "Either your dog or cat eats"

Tags: grammaticality, conjunction-reduction

Version (1) seems correct to me, but I cannot explain why it is correct grammatically. Could someone explain please?

> 1. Either **your dog or your cat** eats my garbage.
> 2. Either **your dog or cat** eats my garbage.

Comment: Please post a comment on why this question is down voted so that I can improve my future posts. I'm honestly trying to learn and don't mean to post useless questions here.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but most likely it's because the question is a bit basic. Why do we usually say *"I'll get my hat and coat"*, for example, rather than *"I'll get my hat and **my** coat"*. Or even *"I'll get my hat and **I'll get my** coat"*. I'd have thought all languages are naturally riddled with examples of [deletion](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/deletion) *- any process whereby sounds or words are left out of spoken words or phrases*

Comment: @FumbleFingers - thanks for the info. I didn't know the grammar rules around this so I posted the question.

Comment: No need to be apologetic. Of the dozens of people who've viewed the question thus far, 3 have upvoted, and 2 have answered. That's 4 (or 5) "favourable" responses (I didn't *upvote*, but I don't know about gmcgath), so a single downvote is nothing to worry about. Most likely essentially the same question has already been asked before - but no-one else has yet found it and voted to close as a duplicate, so you can't be criticised for not finding it yourself before you asked (if indeed that duplicate does exist! :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a question of *correctness*. Most speakers would "delete" the second *your* in most contexts, but if they specifically wanted to pin the blame on *the **addressee's** pets* (rather than another neighbour's pets, for example), they'd probably repeat the pronoun for the sake of emphasis.

Comment: I actually think the repeated *your* can sometimes here make for better rhythm/flow/prosody/balance of the overall sentence, depending on how it gets phrased. Try it a few ways, and it just seems to balance out better in some permutations.

Comment: @tchrist: You're very probably right that prosody is an influence. I wouldn't mind betting the chances of *your* being repeated increase as you replace *dog* and *cat* with 2- or 3-syllable nouns, for example. And it's practically a dead cert you'll repeat it if the first one is some long convoluted noun phrase (but that's probably more to do with clarity/comprehensibility).

Answer (score 6):

This is another example of the common syntactic process called ***[Conjunction Reduction](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/51955/15299)***, which gets rid of repeated material in parallel clauses or phrases. It's optional, so you can do it or not do it, as you like.

There's no difference in meaning, because syntactic processes don't generally affect meaning, but rather structure.  The usual purpose of conjunction reduction is to shorten the spoken sentence.

That's all. In writing, it usually produces ambiguity, and in the wrong hands, occasionally ungrammaticality; in writing one shouldn't delete words without a good reason.

Written language needs all the help it can get to represent spoken language.

Answer (score 0):

To me they are different in meaning but both are correct, the one that repeats the word your means that either your dog or your cat, that is, you have a dog and a cat. The one that doesn't repeat means that the person who says the sentence doesn't know exactly if your animal is either a dog or a cat, the only thing this person knows is that the animal ate his garbage.