# Can I omit "to be" in passive infinitive?

Tags: passive-voice, infinitives

For example,

- *It's fine for the streets to be winding and the street network varied.*
  (in this case, *to be* is repeated in both clauses so it's okay to omit *to be* in second clause)
- *It's fine for the streets to wind and the street network varied.*
  (But, when first infinitive is active and second is passive, can I still omit *to be*?
  I feel I should put *be* before *varied* )

Waiting for your professional advice. Thank you.

Comment: Yes. This is an example of the rule of [Conjunction Reduction](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/96193/15299), which deletes repeated material in conjoined clauses. Notice that _**it's fine for**_ has been deleted, like _**to be,**_ from the original compound sentence _It's fine for the streets to be winding and **it's fine for**  the street network **to be** varied._

Comment: Could you take a look at it again? First one says "to be winding" and second is "to wind". So first one seems fine to me because like you said to be is repeated, but the second one seems wrong because it's conjoined of active and passive. I feel "be" shouldn't be removed. Is that right?

Comment: my question was how to make "varied" part right when it's  "to wind"

Comment: What do you mean by "varied"? Is it supposed to be an adjective or a verb? As a verb, it makes little sense.

Comment: In the second example, use *It's fine for the streets to wind and the street network vary.*

Comment: The second sentence is ungrammatical, since the first clause doesn't contain _to be_ and therefore it isn't deletable in the second clause by Conjunction Reduction, which only deletes repeated material. The second sentence should end _..and the street network to be varied_. Note that the infinitive complementizer _for_  is still deletable, however.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example should be:

> It's fine for the streets to be winding and for the street network to be varied.

The second "to be" could be omitted, if the associated noun is the same. For example:

> It's fine for the streets to be winding and varied.

Your second example should have the "to be":

> It's fine for the streets to wind and for the street network to be varied.

But generally this mix sounds a little off. So, you should prefer to not use a mix.