# Usage of "before" in "I watched the sequel before the original movie"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

Is the following sentence correct:

> I watched the sequel before the original movie.

It sounds strange to me—something like "earlier than the original" or "before I watched the original movie" sounds better, but I'm looking for a definitive rule for the usage of "before".

Can "before" be used together with an object?

Comment: Do you mean "Is 'before' a preposition?" ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  "Before" serves as a correlation/correlative conjunction and functions like a coordinating conjunction in this case, which would allow you to omit repeating the SV.

Comment: What's an SV, as in ". . .repeating the SV"?

Comment: SV means "Subject + Verb" here

Answer (score 3):

Sounds fine to me.

*Before* can be a preposition, a conjunction or an adverb.

*Before watching* makes it a clearer case for being an adverb, whereas *before the original* makes it a clearer case for being a preposition. Regardless of the part of speech, it's correct.

The [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/before_1) has some pretty good examples, some of which are pretty similar under the preposition entry, such as "He arrived before me," where an object pronoun comes into play even though you could just as easily say "He arrived before I did."

If you're set on finding an alternative way to express it, try something more concise like "I watched the sequel first."

Comment: It's all of the above. In English most words swing several ways. In this case, the original sentence is _I watched the sequel before_ **I watched** _the original movie,_ and [Conjunction Reduction](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/51955/15299) removes the repeated subject and verb of the second clause, leaving only the different object _the original movie_.

Answer (score 0):

*Before* can also mean *in front of* as in: *The accused appeared before the judge*.

Comment: That's a preposition, which is not the meaning of "before" in OP.

Comment: Yes, fair enough.