# Adverb placement

Tags: grammaticality, adverb-position, conjunction-reduction

Are these sentences all grammatically correct?

1. I didn't support Gheddafi and I *will never* support him.
2. I didn't support Gheddafi and *will never* support him.
3. I didn't support Gheddafi and *never will* support him.

Comment: I also need to know whether or not I have to put a comma before "and".

Comment: The whole question about adverb placement is notoriously difficult - rules seem extremely complex. It is generally agreed that the permitted positioning of adverbs is very flexible. Your (1) and (3) are fine; (2) sounds a bit 'weak', and I'd avoid it myself, but that's prosodic, not down to grammar. (2) is, after all, merely an ellipted form of (1). I'd say the use of a comma is optional in all three versions; I'd use it if I wanted to indicate a pause in delivery.

Comment: Calling _never_ an adverb is of no use; _never_ is a negative, and has its own special syntax.

Comment: @JohnLawler "Never" is an adverb according to many well-known dictionaries like Cambridge, Oxford and Artha. What about the big elephant sitting in the corner of the room which is my question?

Comment: @Bright, John Lawler is a linguist who has his ***personal*** point of view on English language and puncutation, and, alas, no one here can confute what he says.

Comment: _Adverb_ is a wastebasket category. It covers everything that doesn't fit well into the other seven, so many different kinds of word get labelled adverbs. Consequently, there is no consistent set of rules for adverb usage; there **is**, however, a consistent set of rules for **negative** usage, and that's why using the correct label can be useful. That's all.

Comment: @John Lawler I respect you big time. Thank you for clarifying that to me. I wonder if you would mind telling me about your point of view with regards to sentence number two, do you think it is correct?

Comment: 1'- I supported Gheddafi and I WILL ALWAYS support him. Few would argue that the word **always** is not an adverb, and the distribution would be identical in these three examples. I'm with John Lawler on the overuse of the adverb analysis, but would argue that the distribution even of adverbs defined strictly as 'words modifying verbs only' is fairly unpredictable. eg *Always, we take the garbage out at night. **but** Usually, we take the garbage out at night.

Comment: Quantificational adverbs work like negatives, for the most part. Any operator (Modal, Negative, Quantifier) works that way; operators have a focus and are often separated from it by syntactic rules. That's why there's Neg-Raising, Quantifier-Shift, and lots of other syntactic phenomena.

Comment: I can't see a vast inherent difference between _infrequently_ (or _seldom_) and _occasionally_ (or often), but they have different distributions. _Very_ licenses the fronting of _infrequently_, but I'd say not of _seldom_. Would these adverbs be classed as quantificational adverbs?

Comment: Rhanghyeyun Kim, at  http://mercury.hau.ac.kr/kggc/Publications/SIGG/SIGG10/SIGG10207_RKim.pdf , says: < [I]t has been observed in the literature that this free distribution [of adverbs] in fact applies only to some types of  adverbs and further that even these types of adverbs exhibit meaning change depending on the position in which they occur. ... Jackendoff (1972) classifies adverbs into six major types with respect to their possibilities of occurrences in a sentence ... > Reading further, I'd accept that 4 of Jackendoff's 'six major types' (at least) do contain words I'd class as adverbs.

Comment: I would say "never" is an adverb of frequency. You ask 'how often" and, of course, it has negative function as John Lawler says.

Comment: @tchrist Thank you for the unpaid work. Do get out into the great outdoors sometimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different factors at work in the three sentences, all of which feature automatic pronominalization (*Gheddafi* ==> *him*) in the second clause.

**Sentence 1** is the basic sentence. Two main clauses conjoined with *and*. Both clauses have first person singular subject (***I***), and both clauses have verb phrases headed by auxiliary verbs (*did* and *will*). This is certainly grammatical.

**Sentence 2** is just Sentence 1 after [Conjunction Reduction](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/51955/15299) has applied. That process deletes the repeated *I* subject in the second clause, thus reducing the conjoined clauses to a single clause with a single subject, but a conjoined verb phrase. This is also grammatical. Neither 1 nor 2 is problematic, and there is no meaning difference between them; both occur and individual usage varies.

**Sentence 3** is Sentence 2 with a different placement of *never*. This is where noticing that *never* is a [negative](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf) turns out to be useful, since the rule for negative placement says that

> A negative may occur
> **either** immediately before its "focus"
> (the constituent in the sentence that's getting negated -- here it's the verb phrase *support him*)
> **or** immediately before the beginning of any constituent that **contains** the focus.

So the following are all OK:

- *I will never support him.*
- *I never will support him.*
- *I have never supported him.*
- *I never have supported him.*

because *will support him* and *have supported him* are VPs that contain the focussed VP. So *never* can go either immediately before *will/have*, or immediately before *support(ed)*. Again, such placement makes no difference in meaning or grammaticality; this is another matter like Conjunction Reduction where individual usage varies.

Answer (score 0):

1- I didn't support Gheddafi and I WILL NEVER support him.

2- I didn't support Gheddafi and WILL NEVER support him.

3- I didn't support Gheddafi and NEVER WILL support him.

1 -I didn't support Ghaddafi and I *shall* never support him

2 -I didn't support Ghaddafi and *shall* never support him.

Number two sounds better, though. You have already mentioned it is you who is supporting him. About the replacement for will, shall sounds better, even if it is old fashioned.