# What does "any or any" mean in a legal text?

Tags: grammar, terminology, legalese

I have been going through several legal documents lately and have realised that a lot of them use the fragment "any or any" within some sentences.

> Failing to place a guard or fence or warning signs so as to give any or any adequate warning it was in a dangerous condition and a trap to persons lawfully using the same

Any ideas what purpose "any or any" serves here? I mean, when one uses the word "any" that doesn't need to subsequently be qualified as it is all-encompassing; well, at least that's what I thought.

Comment: If I'm interpreting it correctly, what it's saying is that failing to give any (warning) or any *adequate* warning... Parsing it that way clarifies that there is considered to be a difference between any warning and any adequate warning, legally.  Unfortunately, the way the your question is worded, it's not really a question.  You may consider rewording the heading.

Comment: It is only a lawyer's jargon, and not any actual text of law. The law itself always speaks eloquently, clearly and conspicuously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you analyze the sentence and turn it into the lexical units that it consists of, you get something like this:

> Failing to place a guard
>   or *a* fence
>   or warning signs
>   so as to give
>   **any *warning***
>   **or any adequate warning**
>   *that* it
>   was
>   in a dangerous condition
>   and a trap
>   to persons
>   *who were* lawfully using the same [= **it**]

The word *warning* is elided from the sentence you quoted. Perhaps the defendant will claim that *a warning was given*. The plaintiff's complaint or the law (I don't know which has been quoted here) says that *even if a warning was given, it did not meet the legal requirements if it was not an adequate warning*. This means that **any or any** is not a complete phrase.

Comment: Right, so it's a bit of a tautology (in everyday English) but because of how tightly-sealed legalities must be, the seemingly redundant repetition merely serves to cover all bases?

Comment: And with the "any [warning] or any adequate warning" could you say that modifiers are subject to the distributive property, such that (modifier1 + modifier2) (modified) = (modifier1 + modified) + (modifier2 + modified)?

Comment: @JamesS: Yes. Just as Andrew Leach's answer points out. Lawyers are nitpickers & pettifoggers. They'll use any excuse to wriggle their clients out of being liable for a tort. Yes to your second comment as well. English works that way: we often drop what we consider to be unnecessary (_optional_) words.

Comment: [Conjunction Reduction](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/51955/15299) at work again!

Answer (score 6):

It's not "any or any", it's "any or *any adequate*", that is

> ... so as to give *any warning* or *any adequate warning* it was ...

One might think that the "any warning" was superfluous, because giving no warning at all is a failure to give an adequate warning, but lawyers like to cover all bases.