# Conjunction reduction and singular/plural ambiguity

Tags: grammar, nouns, articles

There is **one** XYZ formulation and **one** ABC formulation.

The original statement is:
[…] that allows for a comparison between the XYZ formulation and the ABC formulation.

Which of the following mean the same/are also correct?

1. […] that allows for a comparison between the XYZ and ABC formulation.
2. […] that allows for a comparison between the XYZ and the ABC formulation.
3. […] that allows for a comparison between the XYZ and ABC formulations.

Comment: (2) needs formulations, but (3) uses conjunction reduction in a standard fashion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Singular or plural usage for ellipsis in direct object](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114646/singular-or-plural-usage-for-ellipsis-in-direct-object) etc.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, thanks so far but (3) make it sound like there are several XYZ formulations and several ABC formulations which is not the case. There is only one of each.

Comment: @hveng, Actually the XYZ and ABC are the two that make the plural of formulations even though there is one of each.

Comment: I'm going with *a comparison between the two formulations—XYZ and ABC*.

Comment: English has built-in ambiguities. 'I saw red and blue birds in the garden' doesn't tell you how many (other than 1 or more of each). Deletions (including conjunction deletions) can add ambiguity. (2) here is ungrammatical, needing the plural. If not precise enough, you must avoid the deletion.

Comment: For the same reason, I'd also pluralize "formulation" in (1). Making it singular implies that there is only formulation, which can be described as both "XYZ" and "ABC".

Comment: thank you all for your effort