# The main verb of the second clause

Tags: verbs, relative-clauses, sentence-patterns, conjunction-reduction

> The energy source on Voyager2 is not a nuclear reactor, in which atoms are actively broken apart, but rather a kind of nuclear battery that uses natural radioactive decay to produce power.

What is the main verb of the clause followed by the coordinating conjunction *but*?

Answer (score 5):

Not only is the **verb** missing from the second clause, so is the **Subject**.

They are deleted by the rule of [Conjunction Reduction](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/51955/15299), which has been applied to two conjoined **clauses**, deleting the (repeated) subject and auxiliary *be*.

Stripped of modificational bells and whistles, the original compound sentence is

- *The power source is not a nuclear reactor*
  *but rather*
  ***the power source is*** a nuclear battery.

and the second occurrence of *the power source is* gets deleted because it's predictable.
producing the compound [Verb Phrase](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf)

- *is not a nuclear reactor but a nuclear battery*

Answer (score 2):

The second verb in the clause beginning with 'but' is the implied verb 'is'.

You could rephrase the sentence as:

> The energy source on Voyager2 is not a nuclear reactor, in which atoms are actively broken apart, but ***is*** rather a kind of nuclear battery that uses natural radioactive decay to produce power.