# Parallel structures problem with their prepositions and helping verbs

Tags: prepositions, parallelism

This might clear it up.

> It is not *about reducing* the consumption of sugars or carbohydrates but *about moderating* the consumption of them.

Does this work correctly? Another example:

> Any person who eats based on a good diet *will lose* weight and *will have* a healthier life.

Is this the correct way of creating the parallel structures, or should the helping verbs/prepositions of the verb be omitted?

Comment: They may be omitted, but every time you omit a marker, you increase the probability of ambiguity. The **real** parallel structure is two separate sentences. As soon as they get combined into one sentence with two clauses, repeated chunks start getting deleted, and have to be inferred by the listener. If the listener is well-trained (i.e, if the writer has been consistent in using parallel structures like this, up to this point), the listener will probably get it. But they do have to be trained, like any interpretive system.

Comment: I understand the verb [to moderate](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define+moderate&oq=define+moderate&aqs=chrome.0.57.590j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=moderate&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=oGK3UcifBYjB0gWk04DICg&ved=0CCwQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47534661,d.d2k&fp=8ffa128ff31ae1ad&biw=1296&bih=930) to mean *to make or become less extreme, intense, rigorous, or violent.* So example #1 seems nonsensical to me.

Comment: I don't understand the question. "This might clear **what** up"? That introduction and @JohnLawler comments referring to "They" & "markers" with no indication of what is being referred to, suggest that this is a continuation of an earlier discussion in a parallel universe.  Please clarify for those of us in *this* universe!

Comment: @TrevorD I'm missing the terminology. The question refers to using some verbs in "sequences" or "repeatedly". Should those verbs be accompanied by a helping verb or not?

Comment: Now, what is it that has four pairs of pants, lives in Philadelphia and it never rains but it pours?

Comment: It's a question about the limits of [conjunction reduction](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/51955/15299), that's all.

Answer (score -1):

Here, in your example, the "about" helps as you repeated it.