# "Good to hear" vs "Glad to hear"

Tags: word-choice, conversational-deletion

Which one is correct:

**Good to hear you enjoyed the radio show.**

or:

**Glad to hear you enjoyed the radio show.**

Comment: In short, "*I* am glad to hear," "*It* is good to hear."

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In terms of their conversational meaning, they are completely synonymous. Use whichever one you feel like.

There is a very subtle difference in meaning, in that the first expands to *It's good to hear that you enjoyed the radio show*, while the second expands to something like *I'm glad to hear that you enjoyed the radio show*. Because of this, the second is slightly more personal, and the first slightly more general.

This difference basically never matters in conversation.

Answer (score 13):

There is no real **pragmatic** difference;
both are appropriate, both are grammatical, and both express the same sentiment.

There is a very small **semantic** difference,
between personal and general satisfaction.

However, there is a very large **syntactic** difference between the two expressions.
Both of them are examples of [Conversational Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/15299), which deletes expectable initial words.
In this case, the two expressions come from very different sentences:

---

The first one

- *Good to hear you enjoyed the radio show*

comes from the sentence

- *(It's) good to hear (that) you enjoyed the radio show.*
  via *that*-Deletion, and Conversational Deletion, which deletes the predictable
  contraction of a dummy *it* subject and auxiliary for a predicate adjective: ***(It's)*** good.

This sentence comes in turn from the sentence

- *To hear that you enjoyed the radio show is good.*
  via [Extraposition](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/57519/15299), which licenses the dummy *it* that gets deleted in conversation.

Note that this sentence doesn't say **who** it's good for;
the experiencer of goodness is `Indef`.

---

The other expression

- *Glad to hear you enjoyed the radio show.*

comes from the sentence

- *(I'm) glad to hear (that) you enjoyed the radio show.*
  via *that*-Deletion and Conversational Deletion, just like the first one;
  what gets deleted is a contracted subject and auxiliary for a predicate adjective:
  ***(I'm)*** glad.

This looks similar to the first one, but note that it does say **who** is glad;
the experiencer of gladness is identified as the speaker, not just `Indef`.

Answer (score 2):

Either is correct English but "glad" is more personal. You're suggesting you personally are happy to hear that they enjoyed the show, whereas "good to hear" just means it's good [for someone] to hear.

Edit - or, @choster put it so nice and succinctly,
"**I** am glad to hear," "**It** is good to hear."