# Best stay close = You'd better/best stay close?

Tags: meaning, phrases, parts-of-speech, ellipses

Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone is full of "Best do smth." phrases:

- *They're goblins. Clever as they come, but not the most friendly of beasts. Best stay close.*
- *Best not to mention this to anyone, Harry.*
- *Best do it a bit of a run if you're nervous.*

What are these phrases from a grammatical standpoint? Could it be a shortened variant of "You'd best" or the Imperative Mood?
Is "Best do smth." used in modern everyday speech?

Comment: It would be best if you...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meaning of the phrase "Four pounds if he's an ounce"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167706/meaning-of-the-phrase-four-pounds-if-hes-an-ounce). And answered at [“Good to hear” vs “Glad to hear”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/147370/good-to-hear-vs-glad-to-hear/147381#147381).

Comment: Used when subject is self evident.

Comment: I think most of the "best do smth." quotes are spoken by Hagrid, and _'e be a bit of a country boy what don't speak Standard English_

Comment: To answer your last question, it is still in everyday use, but at least in the US, that use is localized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [ellipsis](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ellipsis), and it's commonly used in speech to miss out words.  If it were written, the writer may put 'It would be best if you stayed close', but that is long-winded, and it is easier (especially in tense situations, where this would apply) to say 'best stay close.'

Comment: Thank you for a clear answer. This option hasn't occurred to me at all...
In this case could the sentence ''It would be best if you stayed close'' be the subjunctive mood?

Comment: @Hedgehog yes, I think so (not 100% sure)