# Is there a term for not starting a sentence with the word "I"?

Tags: terminology, informal-writing

Is there a name for a statement (either written or spoken) that excludes the subject "I"?

Some example statements are:

- "Happy to provide any additional information you might need."
- "Appreciate you taking the time to answer my question."
- "Obviously, just a huge fan of this site."

I often see this in business communication or situations where the writer/speaker is attempting some kind of "formality" and would love to have a name for the thing that irritates me. A linguistic explanation would be great, although a psychological explanation would be equally welcome.

Comment: Could you tell me why the linguistic phenomenon irritates you? I wouldn't be irritated by any of your examples as long as they're spoken (even in a business setting). If in writing, however, I agree it could be a bit inappropriate.

Comment: Another duplicate: [Good to hear. vs Glad to hear.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/147370/good-to-hear-vs-glad-to-hear/147381#147381) And perhaps the best: [Why is the subject omitted in sentences like 'Thought you'd never ask'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66972/why-is-the-subject-omitted-in-sentences-like-thought-youd-never-ask/66994#66994)

Comment: I first noticed the phenomenon at my workplace, in company-wide emails from C-level executives, and interpreted it as an abdication of personal accountability for the statement. Now that I know the name(s) for it I can do more targeted research to see if this association of mine is unique to me or if I can, like, find a support group or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[***left-edge deletion***](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/english-language-and-linguistics/article/abs/leftedge-deletion-in-english-and-subject-omission-in-diaries1/8565903575654D65D2FCC6A6AAC93EAF)

It is a type of [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)) sometimes called conversational deletion.

In these cases, the subject, especially the pronoun "I"  can be dropped. When the accompanying verb is "be", that can be dropped also.

> "Appreciate you taking the time to answer my question."

Notice that in this sentence, the verb is 'appreciate', and that remains; however the other 2 examples have dropped the verb "be"

It is a type of language seen in diaries, informal conversations. and sometimes even in  formal ones.

Comment: Covered before at least twice.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I couldn't find it in a search...and I don't answer in comment anymore.

Comment: A quick in-house search for [left-edge deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=left-edge+deletion). Conversational deletion will give a lot more: [conversational deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=conversational+deletion) (x29).

Comment: Third time's a charm...