# Simplifying phrases

Tags: grammar, phrases

Take for an example:

> "Sweet Basil and Genovese Basil"
>
> "Take an apple pie and a cinnamon pie"
>
> "A cpu unit and a GPU unit"

is it legal to simplify it to

> "Sweet and Genovese Basil"?
>
> "Take an apple and a cinnamon pie"
>
> "A CPU and a GPU unit"

Are there cases where it isn't recommended?
When does it impact clarity?

Comment: 'Red and white roses' is inherently ambiguous. And worse, attempting to delete your example further to 'Take an apple and cinnamon pie' changes the meaning. One has to be careful when deleting (though inherent ambiguities are often considered acceptable in English where context and/or pragmatics resolve/s the issue). // It's not good to delete disparate items (We met a football and a fund manager / John lost his wallet and temper.) But too broad a question, really. Articles have been written on deletion.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth May I have the link?

Comment: Unit is redundant on CPU/GPU (Central Processing Unit/Graphical Processing Unit)

Comment: [John Lawler](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120498/use-of-elide-common-or-esoteric/120514#120514) lists some types of deletion you can search for. He also gives a good explanation of [conjunction reduction](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51930/i-verb-and-am-rest-of-sentence/51955#51955).