# Ellipsis in noun phrases with possessive case

Tags: possessives, syntactic-analysis, ellipses

Can you omit the second occurrence of the word "poems" in a sentence like the following?

```
I like Lord Byron's poems, and also enjoy a number of Percy Shelley's [poems].
```

Comment: [*I'll show you mine if you show me yours*.](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I'll+show+you+mine+if+you+show+me+yours%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) You can omit *both* occurrences of the relevant noun if you want.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_ellipsis

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better suited to [ell.se]

Comment: So maybe you should change the name of this website to "English Language Advanced Elite Only" or something to avoid people mistakenly thinking that it is about everything English-related? (as the current name suggests)  :q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Also, extending @FumbleFingers' comment, you could even omit the first "poems":

> I like Lord Byron's (and also enjoy a number of Percy Shelley's) poems.

Comment: Another case of [Conjunction Reduction!](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/51955/15299) (Now with XK-25)