# As well as + verb-ing

Tags: grammar, verbs

I am a bit unsure about putting a verb in the "ing" form when it follows "as well as". Can somebody please explain which one (A or B) is grammatically correct and which one sounds more natural?

> A. He documented a number of processes and workflows as well as
>   **liaising** between the development team and its internal clients.
>
> B. He documented a number of processes and workflows as well as
>   **liaised** between the development team and its internal clients.

Comment: B sounds close. Try "He documented a number of processes and liaised between the teams as well".

Comment: document _ed_ -> liais _ed_; document _ing_ -> liais _ing_

Comment: Even though second sentence sounded good to me, after some search I found out that _ing_ form should be used after "as well as" (unless there is an infinitive in the first part, in this case bare infinitive in the second part is preferable). `As well as breaking his arm, he hurt his leg` `I like to dance as well as sing`

Comment: @Vilmar Please provide reference for your research. I suspect you are generalising inappropriately from an alleged 'rule'.

Answer (score 4):

Match the endings

> A. He had been documenting a number of processes and workflows as well as liaising between the development team and its internal clients.
>
> B. He documented a number of processes and workflows as well as liaised between the development team and its internal clients.

Comment: Supplementing this answer: The subject of your second clause is the same as the first clause: "He documented ... [he] liaised ..."; He had been documenting ... [he had been] liaising ..."; NOT "He documented ... [he] liaising ...".

Comment: Basic [Conjunction Reduction](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/51955/15299). Start with everything and delete repeated material recursively, but stop before you overcomplicate the syntax or underspecify the meaning.

Comment: And how does my answer deserve a down vote?

Comment: It seems to me that you should be able to replace “as well as” with “and” – anything appropriate for the latter should be fine for the former, no?

Comment: I do not agree. The and implies a ranking where the second thing was done later or not as important as the first. As well as indicates concurrency

Answer (score 2):

A is correct. Try inverting the clauses, and you can see that the sentence works equally well this way round:

'As well as liaising between the development team and its internal clients, he documented a number of processes and workflows.'

I cannot explain the grammar of this usage, but as a native English speaker and erstwhile professional sub-editor I know that A sounds idiomatic and B does not.