# How to combine in a sentence two verb–preposition pairs that have the same TWO objects?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, prepositions, parallelism, indirect-objects

How could one combine *succinctly* two verbs with the same two objects with different prepositions? For example, if I can either add gifts *to* a box and remove gifts *from* the box, what would be the most natural way of saying that I can do both?

If I would only talk about the gifts, I could say "I can add and remove gifts;" if I would only talk about the box, I could say "I can add to and remove from the box." Now, how can I say both things at once?

Comment: [Conjunction Reduction](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/51955/15299) deletes repeated material, so it will get you as far as _I can both add gifts to the box and remove them (from it)._ The second preposition phrase is optional because it contains no information not already provided by _remove_. But there's no verb that means both give and receive, unless you simply want to use _transfer_, and then you'd have to use the preposition phrase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"I can add gifts to the box and remove them." That you'd be removing them from the box is implicitly clear. (Nobody prevents you from clarifying by appending a "from there", of course, but you are specifically asking for succinctness.)

Comment: To me, that sentence needs the additional two words "from it" (or "from there"). It doesn't matter that they have no additional semantic content; the sentence isn't complete without them.