# "A and B both are" vs. "A and B are both" vs. "Both A and B are" vs. "Both of A and B are"?

Tags: meaning, differences, semantics

> 1. A and B both are very good;
> 2. A and B are both very good.
> 3. Both A and B are very good.
> 4. Both of A and B are very good.

Are there subtle differences between the four sentences above?

Comment: I don't think you would use "of" except with a pronoun, e.g. "Both of them are very good".

Comment: @augurar: I think that's right. The other ones (1-3) are natural results of quantifier syntax.

Comment: @augurar: You'd use it with a plural noun as well.  Eg: "Both of the pies are very good."  But yeah, "both of A and B" sounds rather odd to me.

Answer (score 9):

"Subtle differences?" Hmmmm.

Well, there are some simple differences; dunno how subtle they are. Depends.

I agree with @augurar that (4) is ungrammatical, except for unstressed *them*.
That leaves (rearranging the order a little to show the Q-float direction of *both*):

3. ***Both** A and B are very good.*
4. *A and B **both** are very good.*
5. *A and B are **both** very good.*

These all mean the same thing.

> And here's a couple more sentences that **these all** come from, via [conjunction reduction](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/51955/15299):

- *A is very good.*
- *B is very good.*

> (or perhaps I should say "that **all these** come from", because that's Q-Float, too.)

Here's what's going on.

First, *both* means **all two*;
   that is, *both* has the same syntactic pattern as
   *all (integer) `X`*, which only occurs with `X >` 2
   -- *all three of them, all 27 of them, both/all of them.*

Second, *both* and *all* (and *some, each, any, few,* and quite a few more) are **quantifiers**.
Quantifiers are special words that normally modify noun phrases (as in [1.] above).

Third, in English there is a rule called "Quantifier-Float" that allows some (but by no means all) quantifiers -- *both* or *all* in this case -- to detach themselves from the noun phrase that they bind, and float away to an adverb niche in the verb phrase. Without, naturally, changing meaning.

That's what happened to [2.] and [3.] above; those are the two available [adverb niches](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/Niching.pdf) in that verb phrase:  either right **before** the first auxiliary verb -- *are* -- or right **after** it.

That's all, really.

Comment: Float is, at least sometimes, used to shift focus, and thus the semantics.

Comment: Can do. But that's not syntax; that's pragmatics. At least.

Comment: You might also have mentioned "**A and B are good**". Kind of the elephant in the room here. "Both" is redundant here, but it can emphasize. It can also clarify, if the sentence is more complex (as @JohnLawler points out).  And then there is "**Each of A and B is good**".  It means the same thing in general, but it emphasizes that they are each individually good.  (Whereas "both" can sometimes suggest that they share a property together, without necessarily each enjoying it individually.)

Comment: There are two elephants, which I mentioned: _A is very good_ and _B is very good._ Conjoin them with _and_ and you can do various kinds of conjunction reduction on it ([check the link](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/51955/15299)). _A and B are very good_ is one such product.

Answer (score 2):

- A and B both are very good. --> *both* is parenthetical, = "A and B, both, are very good."
- A and B are both very good. --> fine
- Both A and B are very good. --> *A and B* is parenthetical, = "Both, A and B, are very good."
- Both of A and B are very good. --> No parenthetical. *A and B* = "them"

Yes, there's a distinct difference in meaning, the focus, that shifts between 'A and B', 'both' and 'very good': use as needed.

Comment: I saw Prof. JL's answer after posting mine.