# Why to use question form to express non-question sentences?

Tags: grammar, questions

I know, the title is really vague and unclear but let me explain. I keep hearing things like "Do I envy you!" or "Boy, Do I love pizza!" kind of sentences. I know (or at least figured out) those are not real questions and actually the meaning is closer to "Boy, I (do) love pizza!"

What I'm not sure is the difference between "Boy, I love pizza!" and "Boy, Do I love pizza!", or when to use which. What is the grammar rule behind these kind of sentence structures?

Sorry if the question is stupid or too obvious but as a non-native English speaker, I'm having trouble to see the grammar rule behind it.

Thanks for your help.

edit: I'm also not sure what to add as a tag, please feel free to correct me if I have them wrong or suggest additional tags

Comment: The obvious (?) is that the form *do I* is not used only for questions. Calling it 'question form' is thus inaccurate. *Do* is used in *Boy, do I love pizza!* to enthusiastically affirm one's love for that substance.

Comment: Yeah, swapping the _do_ and the _I_ in this case is specifically an example of [Subject-Auxiliary Inversion](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/167729/15299). It happens in all kinds of questions, but also in many other kinds of constructions: _Never **has** anyone complained_, for example.

Comment: Isn't it also a rhetorical question with the implication that the positive answer is obviously correct? If so it correlates with "Is the Pope a Catholic?" and "Does a bear shit in the woods?" In fact I'm sure that I've heard people use the two forms together as in "Do I like Pizza? Is the Pope Catholic?"

Comment: Closed interrogatives like _Boy, do I love pizza!_ can be used as rhetorical questions indirectly conveying exclamatory statements. The implicit meaning is close to that of the exclamative _Boy, how I love pizza!_

Answer (score -1):

They're used as rhetorical questions, with the implication that the answer is obviously yes. Such as, I can't believe you'd even ask that question, of course I do.