# Stative and Dynamic Verbs

Tags: verbs, writing-style, parallelism, stative-verbs, dynamic-verbs

Please explain how a stative verb and a dynamic verb can have the same subject without breaking parallel construction.

How correct and reasonable is this:

I travel around the world and enjoy flying, where travel is a dynamic verb and enjoy a stative verb?

Comment: (1) The term is **Active** verb, not "dynamic"; _own_ is stative, while _rent_ is active, and stative verbs can't be used in the progressive, for instance: **I am owning that house,* vs *I am renting that house.* (2) There is no such thing as "breaking parallel construction". This is not a grammar term, but something a writing teacher made up, so pay no attention to it. English has no prohibition on active and stative verbs sharing subjects through [Conjunction Reduction](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/51955/15299).

Comment: @JohnLawler: According to Wikipedia, *[dynamic verb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_verb)* is the main term and *[active verb](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Active_verb&redirect=no)* is a synonym redirected to it. With the usual grain of salt with which to take Wikipedia, of course.

Comment: Perhaps a fan of CGEL edited it. _Active/Stative_ has been the term in the English syntax literature since at least 1970. As we see daily here, any and every term is used in the English education literature, somewhere, at some time, by some writer, with some meaning.

Answer (score 1):

There are incongruous parallel constructions, but this is a result of incongruous concepts, not of whether or not one or both are stative:

active + active:

> I travel around the world and visit all the well-known beauty spots. :-)
>
> I travel around the world and visit all my neighbours. :-(

active + stative:

> I travel around the world and own my own plane. :-)
>
> I travel around the world and own my own hamster. :-(

stative + stative:

> I have a diploma in cooking and own my own restaurant. :-)
>
> I have a diploma in cooking and own my own hamster. :-(