# Could "that have and will be" be correct?

Tags: grammaticality

I'm having a discussion with a friend about the last sentence on their business profile (see attachment).

[image]

To me, it sounds totally wrong, but I'd like to know whether it actually is. I think it would have to be "that have been and will be",  because otherwise (as it is now),  it says "that have be and will be".

Is either way correct? Why (not)?

Comment: See also [Parallel sentence construction: “I have, and always will trust you”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174156)

Comment: I'd just say "the companies approached by the club"