# Can a be verb and an ordinary verb share the same subject?

Tags: grammar, verbs, conjunction-reduction

Is the following sentence grammatically correct?

> An apple is red and has a spherical shape.

In comparison, I'm pretty sure that the following sentences are correct:

1. An apple is red and green.
2. An apple has a spherical shape and smells like fish.

Comment: Why do you think it's ungrammatical?

Comment: @PeterShor I think ashpool might wonder if it is or not and why because *Bob was wiped down with baby oil and happy* doesn't work too well. So when the head of the Verb Phrase is *BE*, the lower constituents don't seem to be able to co-ordinate if the *BE*s are different types of *BE* - or maybe if the co-ordinates are different types of phrase ... Those kinds of problems make co-ordination very confusing .. I think ...

Comment: This is an example of ***[Conjunction Reduction](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/51955/15299)***. The base sentence is _An apple is red and an apple has a spherical shape._ This is two sentences with [indefinite generic subject noun phrase](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html) _an apple_ and different verb phrases _is red_ and _has a spherical shape_. They're both grammatical, so their conjunction is too. Then the generic subject _an apple_ gets deleted because it's identical in both clauses. And that's all. The verb phrases are different, so they stay. Simple.

Comment: Why do you think *has* isn't a form of 'be?' It *is.*

Comment: Even otherwise, the two kinds of verb are independent of each other and do not need to belong to the same class. There's no such restriction.

Comment: @Kris, _has_ isn't a form of _be_. Was it a typo, or were you making a subtle joke?

Answer (score 0):

> This is an example of [***Conjunction Reduction***](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/51955/15299). The base sentence is An apple is red and an apple has a spherical shape. This is two sentences with indefinite generic subject noun phrase an apple and different verb phrases is red and has a spherical shape. They're both grammatical, so their conjunction is too. Then the generic subject an apple gets deleted because it's identical in both clauses. And that's all. The verb phrases are different, so they stay. Simple. – [John Lawler](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/15299/john-lawler)

Comment: But it's not that simple. It doesn't explain why Araucaria's example _Bob was wiped down with baby oil and happy_ is wrong.

Comment: True, but I think that was not (at all) the OP's question.