# Using the word "whether" instead of "which"

Tags: word-choice, grammar, relative-pronouns, tech-writing, correlative-conjunctions

Can I use the word "whether" instead of "which" as in the following sentence?

"How to Decide Whether to Use Product A or Product B" (this is a heading)

I would usually write it as "How to Decide which to Use: Product A or Product B" 
or just "When to Use Product A or Product B".

If the first example with "whether" is acceptable, in what situation is it more suitable than other two ways of suggesting options?

Answer (score 7):

Just as *where* is the *wh*-word that goes in front of questions about location, *whether* is the *wh*-word that goes in front of *yes/no* questions when they're subordinated:

- *Is he going (or not)?* ~ *I wonder **whether** he's going (or not)*.

Since *yes/no* questions imply a binary choice, a conjoined *or not* phrase may often be added.
For the same reason, embedded question complements headed by *whether* can often use *if* instead:

- *I wonder **if** he's going (or not).*

Unlike other *wh*-words, *whether* is never used to mark a regular question:

- **Whether is he going?*

because *yes/no* questions already do that without a *wh*-word.

- *Is he going?*

In this case, *whether* can introduce two conjoined infinitive clauses

- *whether **for me** to buy sugar puffs or **whether for me to buy** coco pops*

reduced by [conjunction reduction](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/51955/15299) by deleting the optional boldface above, to

- *whether to buy sugar puffs or coco pops*

So it's fine provided it is introducing a *yes/no* question or some binary opposition.

Comment: +1 Useful post.  Might be worth mentioning that the *or not* being mandatory only applies if the clause is functioning as a conditional adjunct. (... Or it might not).

Comment: Thanks. I corrected the ambiguous sentence; _or not_ phrases are never mandatory, always optional.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightening answer. This addresses a question that was on my mind, which is, whether it is always acceptable to substitute "if" for "whether". Can you think of any examples where this wouldn't be the case?

Comment: Well, the first example sentence has a _Wh_-infinitive construction,  _whether to use Product A or Product B_. _Wh_-words can take infinitive complements, but _if_ can't: *_if to use Product A or Product B_.

Comment: @John Just a minor note: the _or not_ phrase is mandatory when the _whether_ clause indicates the applicability of the main clause regardless of which outcome is true, e.g., “You’re coming whether you like it or not”; leaving it out and saying just, “You’re coming whether you like it” would be, if not ungrammatical, then at least highly unusual.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have grasped the usage quite well.

The following two sentences mean exactly the same thing:

1. I must decide which to buy: sugar puffs or coco pops.
2. I must decide whether to buy sugar puffs or coco pops.

Comment: I'd use a colon.

Comment: Thank you WS2 for the advice, and also Edwin for pointing out the use of colon. Which one would you guys use for my example: which or whether?

Comment: @user77176 Probably the second, unless it made for a long and complicated sentence that was difficult to follow - it is not always simply about sugar puffs and coco pops!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Quite right. Duly amended.

Answer (score 2):

**Which** is the clear favorite if you have more than two choices or if you do not want to list all of the choices. As other answers note, **whether** implies a binary choice.

Imagine you are going to get a kitten, and you get to pick from a litter of nine kittens. Which sounds better?

> I don't know which kitten to bring home.
>   I don't know whether to bring home the white one, or the spotted one, or the calico one, or the runt, or the tabby-looking one...

The first is unmarked, the second means that you are violating Grice's maxim of brevity (and are therefore communicating something in addition to your hesitation at choosing).

Answer (score 1):

*Whether* implies a choice to be made and focuses on the question as a whole, and usually involves two options, even if one is to not make a choice.

*Which* means pick from available (known) options.

They are not interchangeable in the sentence without also adjusting punctuation.

Comment: SrJoven, thank you for your comment. Unfortunately I have not grasped the difference between the two from your explanation... "choice to be made" and "pick from available options" seem the same to me. Which one would you use for my example?

Comment: I'm not sure how better to explain it. You didn't ask me *Whether one would you use...?*. Why not? Because you asked me to pick (exactly one choice) from a list. If you asked me *Whether I should A or B?* It would be different. But before asking which vs whether, look in a dictionary, and find out what still is unclear to you.

Comment: Hi SrJoven, I was misreading your comment. Sorry and thank you for your patience.