# "I don't know whether/*if or not I passed"

Tags: conjunctions, disjunction, if-whether

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/if#Usage_notes) says

> The sentences *“I don't know **whether or not** I passed”* or “I don't know **whether/if** I passed **or not**” are both correct.

> The sentence […] but “*I don't know **if or not** I passed*” is incorrect.

Why is it so?

> **[WHETHER OR NO](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/whether)**: <sub>CONJ</sub>
> 3. used as a conjunction as a variant of *whether*
> 4. under any circumstances: *he will be here tomorrow, **whether or no***.
> <sub>Source: WordReference</sub>

**OED**: IF https://oed.com/oed2/00111435 , WHETHER https://oed.com/oed2/00284376

Comment: Is the question about "whether or not"/"if or not" or is it about "whether or no"? The last quotation comes across as a non sequitur.

Comment: The more you add links, the more your question becomes ambiguous. If you asked different questions about each of the issues raised here, I doubt they would be closed.

Comment: @HotLicks valid 99% of the time  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_universal

Comment: I posted on [_if/whether_ a while back](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/362814/152990).

Answer (score 4):

"*Whether or no*" is an alternative to "*whether or not*" and it means exactly the same.

It appears in the nursery rhyme *'A frog he would a-wooing go'*:

> A frog he would a-wooing go,
> Hey ho! said Rowley,
> A frog he would
> a-wooing go,
> **Whether his mother would let him or no**.
> With a rowley powley, gammon and spinach,
>  Hey ho! said Anthony Rowley.

Fowler (A Dictionary of Modern Usage, 1926) gives other examples of "*or no*" being used the same way:

`Pleasant or no, it is true;`
`He must do it whether he will or no.`

NGram shows "*Whether or no*" falling slowly into disuse over the last two hundred years. When it *does* appear nowadays it seems to be mostly in quotations from previous centuries.

Comment: **Sum-of-Parts** since **NO** (adverb) 4. not: _whether or **no**._ https://www.wordreference.com/definition/no

Comment: Furthermore, I don't know what meaning(s) of ''whether'' would **whether or no** be a variant of  https://www.wordreference.com/definition/whether

Comment: @GJC: I don't know what you are saying here. What does "Sum-of-parts since" mean? "Whether or no" isn't a _variant_ of 'whether'.

Comment: ![https://imgur.com/a/bZEZ6ka](https://imgur.com/a/bZEZ6ka).

Answer (score 2):

This is the rule according to [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/if-or-whether) too:

> To express an alternative, we can use ***or not*** with ***if*** and ***whether***. With *whether* we can use *or not* ***immediately after whether or in end position***. With *if* we use *or not* ***in end position only***:
> e.g.
> I called Bill to find out ***whether or not*** he really did go to
> Afghanistan.
>
> I called Bill to find out ***whether*** he really did go to Afghanistan ***or
> not***.
>
> I called Bill to find out ***if*** he really did go to Afghanistan ***or not***.

But people do use ***if not*** erroneously, sometimes just because they don't know the rule:

> the phrase “whether or not”, as in “I was wondering whether or not you
> would come” is okay, but “if or not” in the same context seems not
> okay - google searches bring up 100 million hits for the first phrase,
> but just 15,000 for the second. This came up in a class I was in, and
> I was surprised because I do use “if or not” in informal speech ([painintheenglish](https://painintheenglish.com/case/593))

I am surprised even [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=if%20or%20not%2C%20whether%20or%20not&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cif%20or%20not%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhether%20or%20not%3B%2Cc0) finds instances of *if or not*. I'd recommend you avoid it though, it's not good English.

Here is what [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/whether) says:

> Use ***whether***, but ***not if***, ***immediately before ‘or not’***:
>
> - The question is whether or not the government has the right to interfere.

So there you go. The answer is pretty much what @Hot Licks commented: *"Because English!"*

Comment: **WhETHER OR NO**: 1. used as a conjunction as a variant of **whether** 
2. under any circumstances: _he will be here tomorrow, **whether or no**_ https://www.wordreference.com/definition/whether

Comment: Yes, and? You kinda lost me there :-)

Comment: Might **whether or not** be an idiom too? https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/whether+or+not

Comment: The link you gave is for the case when "whether or not" is synonymous with "regardless"/"whatever happens". Your OP was about the case when "whether or not" can be interchangeable with "if ...  or not" (considering one option of two or more). I am not sure your edit of the OP is helpful. What is the actual question now?

Comment: But what meaning(s) of ''whether'' would **whether or no** be a variant of?  https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/whether#Usage_notes