# Omitting subject or be verb in the second clause

Tags: grammaticality

Which one is the most natural?

1. Such set is called an empty set and it is denoted by 0.
2. Such set is called an empty set and is denoted by 0.
3. Such set is called an empty set and denoted by 0.

Comment: none of those sound right, but it's because of the first part. `Such a set is called an empty set and is denoted by 0.` sounds best to me.

Comment: All the sentences are equally ungrammatical, because _Such_ requires an indefinite article before _set_; i.e, they should all start _Such a set_. As for the other differences, that's just normal [Conjunction Reduction](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/51955/15299); all are grammatical if the subject is changed.

Comment: just as a note, rather than using an indefinite article, you could make *set* plural as long as the verbs agree: `Such sets are called empty sets and are denoted by 0`. plurality is not needed for conveying the intended meaning (and i would not write the sentence this way), but it is "correct" english as well.

Comment: Correct 'english' is 'English'.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on the false assumption that at least one of the choices presented is correct, when in fact not one of them is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the rest of them quibble, I will summarize:  #2 is best, but you need to insert "a" — "Such a set".  Clear?