# Is it correct to say "Can I enter if don't have a ticket"?

Tags: idioms, word-usage

Is it correct to say "Can I come in if don't have a ticket"?

or,

Which is more common in ordinary life:

**A.  Can I enter if don't have a ticket?**

**B.  Can I enter if I don't have a ticket?**

Comment: A more appropriate one would be: Can I enter without a ticket?

Comment: @MamtaD, I just want to know if sentence A is correct grammatically,  though I understand yours are more  appropriate.

Comment: In that case, an "even" would be needed in your sentence. Can I enter even if I don't have a ticket?

Comment: This question is better asked on [ell.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your sentence isn't quite correct...

> Can I come in if don't have a ticket?

You're missing the subject of the clause. You need to add another "I" in there, like so:

> Can I come in if I don't have a ticket?

Of the two sentences you presented, A is problematic but B is fine, and B is therefore more common in ordinary life.

You can sometimes omit redundant subjects (see [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51930/i-verb-and-am-rest-of-sentence/51955#51955)) but not in this case.