# A Sentence in Lost Series

Tags: dialogue

I was watching Lost (again) yesterday and someone said:

*" - Well, then. I guess I won't have to convince you after all."*

*" - I'm not going to kill -spoiler-, Ben. You are."*

My question is: I was expecting the end of the sentence not with a "You are", but with "You will". Why they say "You are"? Is "You will" incorrect?

Thanks!

Comment: [Conjunction Reduction](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/51955/15299) deletes the end of the second sentence by identity with the end of the first sentence. The first sentence was _I am not going to `VP`_, so the second sentence must have been _You are going to `VP`_. The identical part is _going to `VP`_, leaving _you are_ behind. If the first sentence had been _I will not `VP`_, then Conjunction Reduction would work on a second sentence _You will `VP`_, leaving _you will_ behind. But it has to be in both clauses.

Comment: The first sentence uses the progressive construction, so the second does, too. *I am not >>> you are*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quote, if you take out the contraction is:

> *I **am** not going to kill -spoiler-, Ben. You are.*

This is correct and idiomatic.

It's echoing... am --- are

If it had read:

> *I will not kill -spoiler-, Ben.*

**Then** it would read:

> *You will.*