# How to decide on the type of ellipsis

Tags: syntactic-analysis, ellipses, conjunction-reduction

I'm having some hard time deciding on the types of a few ellipses I've got to analyze.

Let's consider an example such as this one:

> Then Rosemary came out and said that Daddy was going to jail, and I hit her." "**[Did you hit her]** Real hard?" "**[I hit her]** Real hard."

In case of this example, I would say both of the ellipses are clausal since the deletion of the subject,the predicate and the object affected the whole clause; the only element of that remaind being the adverbial. These two ellipses would fall into the category of bare argument ellipsis, as far as I know.

But what if there is an ellipsis such as this:

> She loved the child's pink nightie, **[she loved]** the stack of white pillow slips edged with embroidery...

Here, the coordinating "and" is replaced by a comma for a more dramatic effect and the second clause presupposes the subject and the predicate from the first. Would that still count as an example of clausal ellipsis, since without these two elements the second clause is technically incomplete, or would it be better to label it as an example of verb phrase ellipsis? The problem with that would be the fact that subjects are not considered constituents of verb phrases.

Thanks everybody in advance.

Comment: Now *this* is the kind of question I'd like to see more of on this site. Unfortunately, I personally lack the expertise to even approach it. It would also be good if we could attract the attention of some of the grammatical experts who hang out at our sister site, ELL (though this question should remain here and not be asked there; it's just that those guys might have interesting and well-informed ideas to share).

Comment: Are you sure there _is_ an ellipsis, because I'm not. It most certainly isn't a VP ellipsis, since they need to be introduced by an auxillary verb (or `to`).

Comment: @TusharRaj By considering the classification by Wilson (Mind the Gap) and some others (a google search on bare argument ellipsis), these two examples are indeed instances of ellipsis.

Comment: @RóbertBalaško: The first one definitely is. I'm not so sure about the second one. If you're sure it's either VP or clausal, it must be clausal.

Comment: I think it's "over-analysis" to suppose that the second ***Real hard*** in the example as given specifically represents the "elision" of *[I hit her] real hard*. I'd be just as comfortable saying it's simply shorthand for *Yes, "real hard" [would be a very appropriate term]*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers In that case, I would say, the situation tells you that the author of the last sentence is the same as the author of the first, which is an instance of situational ellipsis.

Comment: @Róbert: My point exactly. If you insist on hypothesizing some "longer, more complete" wording for every single case, you'd end up doing something like that whenever someone's contribution to a dialogue is simply *Yes*, for example. Which I could have used instead of my first three words in this comment. But just because I could paraphrase to ***That is** my point exactly*, or *Yes **that is true*** doesn't mean the shorter forms are in any meaningful sense *derived* from those extended forms subjected to specific deletions

Comment: You're handicapped by calling it "ellipsis"; that's a term from Greek rhetoric (not grammar, and particularly not English syntax) and just means "something's missing". Categorizing "ellipsis" is a losing game, since it's already been done by categorizing deletion rules; [there are **a lot** of them](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf), and they operate on different structures, under different conditions, with different words -- and no doubt for different purposes, though they all shorten utterances by omitting expectable material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example cited in the post is clausal ellipses, of course, but I am more inclined to regroup it in the sub category of ANSWER ELLIPSES.

If we closely observe the instance, we would find that two sentences are elliptical:

•(did you hit her) "Real hard?"

•(I hit her) Real hard.

The first sentence is a question but, take my word, it a 'disguised/latent answer which is echoed in the latter. So both are answer fragments. ANSWER ELLIPSES can do with just an adjunct/adverbial even. You may differ but ellipses would allow us that liberty.

As regards the second example, we may call it clausal or(textual) ellipses in general and a case of gapping ellipses in particular. It cannot be a VPE as in that case, a non finite VP is ellided and  the ellipses must be introduced by an auxiliary verb/participle 'to'. Whereas, in GAPPING ELLIPSES, redundant materials often contain a finite verb. An example:

• John can play the guitar, Mary(.....) the violin.

However, an Ellipses is sense without (sensibility) form; a respite for us, isn't it?!

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you have a full clause; in the other, just the verb (and it's subject, English being a non Null-Subject language)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it will help since yours is a matter of rhetorical devices, but have a look at some of the answers I received on a similar issue, especially at the one about *conjunction reduction*:

[I <verb> and am <rest of sentence>](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51930/i-verb-and-am-rest-of-sentence/51955#51955)

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, John Lawler answered:

> You're handicapped by calling it "ellipsis"; that's a term from Greek rhetoric (not grammar, and particularly not English syntax) and just means "something's missing". Categorizing "ellipsis" is a losing game, since it's already been done by categorizing deletion rules; [there are **a lot** of them](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf), and they operate on different structures, under different conditions, with different words -- and no doubt for different purposes, though they all shorten utterances by omitting expectable material.