# What to use?: Infinitive, bare infinitive or gerund as a complement after an expression

Tags: infinitives, gerunds, gerund-vs-infinitive, bare-infinitive, complements

I came across some sentences and I was wondering which word is correct: 'train,' 'to train' or 'training'?

*What we should do is **train** our workers to become more efficient.*

*All I we do is **train** our workers...*

*All you have to do is **train** workers...*

Comment: What you should do is use the site search. All you do is not use the site search. All you have to do is use the site search.

Comment: These iare normal cases of [_Conjunction Reduction_](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/51955/15299), which deletes repeated material in successive phrases or clauses. In this case, the original sentence _What we should do is we should train ..._. Conjunction Reduction has deleted _we should_, for instance. In the second, _we_ is deleted; in the third, _you have to_.

Answer (score 0):

Although your example is quite broken in terms of grammar but this depends upon where you want to use them.

**Infinitive:** All we should do is **to train** our workers.
**Gerund:** You and I should be **training** our workers!
**Bare infinitive** doesn't fits in your example.

The idea is 90% of the times we use Gerunds that is, adding an ***'-ing'*** and that sounds normal in communication written or verbal. While using an infinitive, it sounds quite philosophical or poetic. So, it falls back to your audience or context of usage.

**Gerund:** Eating fruits is healthy.
**Infinitive:** To eat fruits is healthy.

Comment: It looks like you have gerund and infinitive flipped in your bolded examples. Also, "All we should do is to train our workers" isn't grammatical, the sentence should be "All we should do is train our workers".

Comment: @Matt Oh yeah! Thanks for update else it would have been polemical!