# How can word "and" be deleted in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

*This food looked horrible,* *(and)* *even grotesque*.

In this sentence, do I have to put the word *and* before phrase *even grotesque*?
And if I don't have to put the word *and*, what is the rule that allows me to delete the word *and*?

Comment: There are several varieties of _and_-deletion rules. One deletes all but the last _and_ in series (_me, Bill, Harry, and Max_), and another deletes the _and_ between two conjoined sentences, especially when other words have been deleted by [Conjunction Reduction](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/51955/15299). The second type is what this is -- it comes from _The food looked horrible, (and) (the food) even (looked) grotesque_, and all the parenthesized words are deleted; deleting the _and_ is kind of an afterthought. It's not needed because there arenlt two clauses anymore, just two phrases.

Comment: What is this second type called?

Comment: It's part of conjunction reduction; that deletes to the right. The first kind deletes to the left -- i.e, everything but the last is deleted.

Comment: Can you give me some examples? I am so confused right now.

Comment: There was an example in the comment: _me, Bill, Harry, and Max_ comes from _me and Bill and Harry and Max_, and the first two _and_'s have been deleted. Note that they come before the one that is kept. This is the opposite of deleting thee second _the food looks_.

Comment: I am very familiar with me, Bill, Harry, and Max type of phrases. And I know very well that there have to be more than 2 elements in the sentence for every ands except for the last to be deleted. But in my sentence, there are only 2 elements which I thought disabled me to delete  word "and" from. If it is the opposite way of bill, harry, and max phrase, doesn't it have to follow the same rule?

Comment: _And_ would no longer connect two clauses. There was so much deleted from the second clause that it wasn't a clause any more, just a modifier. Adding _and_ would be like adding it to _She's coming home, late_ to make __She's coming home, and late_. You could, if you wanted to stress the second part; but it's not necessary. Like so many things in English, it's up the speaker.

Comment: So it became something like this: This food looked so horrible, (which was) even grotesque. Great amount of deletion just made it a phrase that modifies the first clause "this food looked so horrible." Right? But now there is one more problem: I have seen this sentence in a book. The sentence goes, " Within a couple of days I could stand, even make two, three steps, despite the nausea and general weakness." In this sentence, word "and" that should have come before word "even" is deleted again. And this time it does not seem like this phrase "even ... steps" can be a modifier.

Comment: So why is and deleted again?

Comment: _And_ should link two of the same thing. There used to be two clauses connected by _and_. After all the deletions, you just have a noun phrase after a clause. So you can (but don't have to) delete the _and_.

Comment: So whenever there is just a noun phrase or whichever type of phrase, I am able to delete the and. Does it go same with the other coordinating conjunctions? Or is it possible only with and?

Comment: _Horrible_ and _grotesque_ are coordinating adjectives because they both describe _food_. You can remove the conjunction between coordinating adjectives that are joined by _and_ or _but_.

Comment: @JohnLawler Your answer is correct, and you know it. So, answer the question! You get credit, and so the question can be closed, with a correct answer registered for posterity :)

Comment: @Born2Smile: The idea that there is a rule that covers the deletion of a single word in English and nothing else is so silly that there can be no useful answer and does not deserve one. As I've pointed out. As far as posterity is concerned, I hope they learn not to ask silly questions so much, but experience suggests that isn't gonna happen.

Comment: I kind of wonder how the prize is going to go; does the OP have the points to give away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is half way between a comment and an answer, but I'll state it here. You could use *grotesque even* as an adjunct. More specifically as a supplement. This is a bit like putting the same phrase in brackets:

> This food looked horrible, grotesque even.

Answer (score 6):

An artful way to delete it is to rephrase using the adjective suffix `ly`.

> This food looked horribly grotesque.

The literal meaning is slightly different but the spirit is the same.

Semicolons aren't all that common but they can join two independent clauses and show that they are strongly related.

> This food looked horrible; in fact, it even looked grotesque. [QaDT](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/how-to-use-semicolons?page=3)

If you want to see some masterful use of semicolons read some of Martin Luther Kings speeches.

Some prefer to avoid semicolons.  In this case a simple comma can rid you of the `and`.

> This food looked horrible, even grotesque.

When spoken it leads you to pause briefly.

Comment: I'd use the comma. "Even grotesque" is not an independent clause so the semicolon is inappropriate. In the first option, "horribly" seems more like "extremely" than "in a way that is horrible".

Comment: @mgold hows this?

Comment: As with so much of English, it's what sounds right. Compare, "he's a horribly impatient person."

Answer (score 3):

A comma can separate two adjectives [when the adjectives are interchangeable](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/commas.asp).

[Grammar rules for lists](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/punctuation-in-lists) allow the article separator, *and,* to be replaced with a comma. The comma "stands in" for the word *and,* replacing it.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, 'even' is an adverb used as an intensifier (aka intensive) and meaning 'indeed'. The "and" is a red herring.

> **even**
>
> ....
>
> adv.
>
> 1. .... b. Indeed; moreover. Used as an intensive: *He was happy, even ecstatic.*

(from [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/even))

Note the close parallel between your example and the example in the dictionary.

The "and" in your example is superfluous. In the interest of expressive economy, leave it out.

No *prescriptive* rule covers the case, because 'even' is (already) the connector; however (indeed, moreover), you might well ask what prescriptive rule allows the insertion of 'and' before a connective adverbial intensifier.

As for a *descriptive* "rule" covering the case, the topic would be more appropriate on a linguistics forum. This is beyond my expertise, but my understanding is that the descriptive "rule" ('rule' is used in a figurative technical sense here) would describe how a hypothesized prototypical or idealized linguistic deletion results in the use of connective adverbs without an 'and' component in a specified linguistic environment.

Answer (score 1):

I would just add to what @CandiedOrange said that the main use of semicolons is to join two independent clauses, not clauses and phrases.  Replace the semicolon with a comma and it's perfect -- two descriptive words in apposition to each other (horrible/grotesque), joined by a comma.