# "How good A and how bad B were in their respective roles"?

Tags: grammar, conjunction-reduction

The construction of this sentence is bothering me. Is it grammatically well formed? If not, what is the correct alternative?

> ... a prime example of how terrible Marina Sirtis and how good Brent
>   Spiner were in their respective roles.

Comment: Do you have any specific problem with the sentence? What exactly is bothering you and why didn't you provide the complete sentence?

Comment: As Helmar said, it would help if you provided more specific information about what's bothering you. John Rakoczy thought it was the verb "were," and that also seems the most likely point of confusion to me, but you never indicate this in your post.

Answer (score 2):

> *a prime example of how terrible Marina Sirtis and how good Brent Spiner **were**
>
>   in their respective roles*

There are two *Wh*-clauses (both starting with *how*), and both have subjects (*Marina Sirtis*, *Brent Spiner*) that are singular noun phrases; the *Wh*-clauses they are the subjects of are conjoined with *and* into something like

- *a prime example of

   [how terrible Marina Sirtis was, and how good Brent Spiner was*]

But we haven't mentioned the last phrase yet -- *in their respective roles.* If we put that after the conjoined clauses above,

- *how terrible Marina Sirtis was, and how good Brent Spiner was, in their respective roles*

it seems to cause a problem. Several problems.

First, why do we need a *respective* phrase at all? If you are talking about two people who are doing different things and judging them both, you **have** to judge each in their own role.

For instance, if I review a movie, I might say that one actress was very good, but another actress was not. Obviously, each of them would be playing a different role; they couldn't be playing the same role. So nothing need be said about their roles;
in such cases, it's usually best to say nothing.

Second, how do we get from singular *was* to plural *were*? This is where the problem comes from.

In its simplest form, the rule of [Conjunction Reduction](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/51955/15299) deletes repeated material in conjoined clauses. The material can be subject, object, or both,

- *Bill washed the dishes and **Bill** swept the floor* ==>
  *Bill washed the dishes and swept the floor.*
- *Bill washed **the dishes** and Mary dried the dishes* ==>
  *Bill washed and Mary dried the dishes.*
- *Bill washed **the dishes** and **Bill** dried the dishes* ==>
  *Bill washed and dried the dishes.*

  ... or something else altogether
- *Bill **is tired** and Mary is tired* ==>
  *Bill and Mary **are** tired.*

And here's where the ***are*** shows up. If conjunction reduction results in a conjoined subject
*A and B*, like *Bill and Mary*, then the subject is plural, and governs plural agreement with *were*.

But that's not what happens in the example sentence. The subject there is conjoined,
but it's not two conjoined noun phrases -- it's two conjoined _Wh-_clauses:

- *[how terrible Marina Sirtis was] and [how good Brent Spiner was]*

which come from

- *[M.S. was terrible `to degree X`] and [B.S. was good `to degree Y`]*

If we attempt to apply conjunction reduction to this, we get

- *[M.S. was terrible `to degree X`] and [B.S. good `to degree Y`]*

because *was* is the only repeated word, except the degree quantifier that becomes *how terrible/good*. At no point is there any conjoined plural noun phrase [*M.S. and B.S.*],
so there is no reason for plural *were*.

That's what's bothering you. A rule's been applied where it shouldn't've been.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer based upon the fragment presented:  the adverbs are separated and require separate verbs.

"... a prime example of (both) how terrible Marina Sirtis **was**, and how good Brent Spiner **was** in their respective roles."

or

"... a prime example of how (the performance **was**) terrible for Marina Sirtis and how good (it **was** for) Brent Spiner in their respective roles."

(love Brent Spiner by the way)

Comment: Or you might even go whole-hog with even "...how terrible Marina Sirtis was in her role and how good Brent Spiner was in his."

Comment: @SvenYargs I actually like the complete disambiguation in your version.

Comment: @svenyargs yes, I like your whole-hog version even better.  It's what I meant to say ;)