# Should we use `personal pronoun` multiple times in a sentence?

Tags: personal-pronouns

Example 1: Should we say this

> `The authors` study the load balancing problem and present greedy algorithms for it.

or this

> `The authors` study the load balancing problem and `they` present greedy algorithms for it.

Example 2: Should we say this

> `We` design algorithms for the problem and then `we` show that these algorithms are efficient.

or this

> `We` design algorithms for the problem and then show that these algorithms are efficient.

Comment: What does your research tell you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, both sentences are correct. However, because these are compound sentences, the rule of Conjunction Reduction would apply.

This rule basically says that a common feature of two coordinated sentences can be omitted from the second sentence. [Citation](http://referenceworks.brillonline.com/entries/encyclopedia-of-ancient-greek-language-and-linguistics/conjunction-reduction-SIM_00000433#d21802258e200)

Therefore you should skip the second personal pronoun.

***But***, it should be noted that occasionally it would also be correct to include the second pronoun anyway, in order to add emphasis.

For example, this sentence uses the pronoun twice in order to add emphasis:

> "I washed the dishes and I swept the floor so you need to do the mopping!"

It would be correct to say "I washed the dishes and swept the floor..." but that second "I" makes it clearer to the listener why she or he has to do the mopping!

This discussion on Compound Reduction is also worth reading:

[I <verb> and am <rest of sentence>](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51930/i-verb-and-am-rest-of-sentence/51955#51955)