# Is this example correct? (omitting subject in compound sentence)

Tags: independent-clauses, compound-sentences, subject-drop

Had an argument with my colleague regarding the example from "Advanced Grammar in Use" by Martin Hewings:

> In two years time Morneau will have been acting for 50 years, and
>   shows no signs of retiring from the theatre.

To me it sounds a bit fancy, but clear and grammatically correct. However, my colleague insists that it should be corrected in one of these ways:

1. In two years time Morneau will have been acting for 50 years, and **he** shows no signs of retiring from the theatre.
2. In two years time Morneau will have been acting for 50 years, and **yet** shows no signs of retiring from the theatre.
3. Morneau will have been acting for 50 years **in two years time**, and shows no signs of retiring from the theatre.

So do you think if it's correct grammatically and stylistically? Can someone think of similar sentences, some real life examples?

Comment: It is a bit fancy, but it's perfectly grammatical, an example of what's called [Conjunction Reduction](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/51955/15299), which deletes unnecessarily repeated constituents of conjoined sentences. The comma, btw, indicates an intonation curve that effectively substitutes for the subject, by announcing a new clause continuing the same subject.

Answer (score 1):

The bare bones of your sentence are:

> Morneau | will have been acting **and** shows

It is not a compound sentence, i.e., with two independent clauses, but a simple sentence with one subject and a compound verb joined by *and*. By the rules of traditional grammar, the comma [should not be there](https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/modulecomma.htm). Or you may add the pronoun *he* to produce the second independent clause, as your friend suggests, but doing so merely to satisfy a comma rule doesn’t seem especially satisfactory either: there is no ambiguity as to who the subject of *shows* is. So why bother?

The other suggestions are merely stylistic, but still don’t deal with the comma problem. Adding a contrastive, either *and yet* or just *yet* as a conjunction, changes the meaning of the sentence. Sticking *in two years time* at the end of the clause merely makes the future perfect sound clumsy, so it’s hardly an improvement.

In longer sentences,however, especially as here where the verbs are different tenses, even the best writers toss in a comma. The best solution, then, would be either toss the comma or leave the sentence as is.

Comment: I might be wrong, but can we consider verbs in different tenses as compound verb? I don't mean simple cases, but future perfect progressive & present simple do not seem to work as a part of a single clause.

Comment: Two or more verbs joined by a conjunction and having the same subject form a compound verb. The tense is irrelevant.