# Syntactic Characteristics of Coordination

Tags: grammar

Is it grammatically correct to say

1. ***John plays the guitar and Mary, the piano*** .....

when it comes to the syntactic features of **Coordination**

Comment: (1) is an example of [Conjunction Reduction](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/51955/15299), and is grammatically correct English. The comma is unnecessary with phrases this short.

Comment: Your main Q. has been answered, but your 'plea for help' is far too open-ended and vague for this site.  If you can be much more ***specific*** about what help you need, then please raise another Q.  For that reason, I'm deleting the last line of your Q. in preference to proposing the entire Q. for deletion.