# Need of subject after 'But'

Tags: conjunctions

we often  see these 
1. Liza is poor but she is honest.
2. Liza is poor but honest.
Is their any rule against the first one?
which one is preferable?

Comment: Duplicate; conjunction reduction.

Comment: Can you explain, please?

Comment: Explained by TaliesinMerlin at [Is _We sang and danced_ a compound sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/494507/is-we-sang-and-danced-a-compound-sentence/494526#494526). Here, the second sentence is merely a variant of the first, using what is known as 'conjunction reduction'. Both are perfectly grammatical. The shortened version is more compact and flows more smoothly, but the full version lends itself better to dramatic emphasis. Your choice, every time you use such a sentence.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help