# Singular or plural after Subject + modal + base form of the verb

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

For example:

> A well thought-out system streamlines operation, improves work
>   process, reduces data redundancy.....

If ***can*** is added to the sentence, should the following verb be singular or plural?

> A well thought-out system can streamline operation, *improve* work
>   process, *reduce* data redundancy.....

or

> A well thought-out system can streamline operation, *improves* work
>   process, *reduces* data redundancy.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb "can" is modifying all three verbs, not just the first one (all three verb-object pairs are predicates of "can"). Therefore, all three verbs are in their **infinitive form**, and do not inflect for the 3rd person singular. No "-s" ending is required.

This is not about singular vs. plural conjugation, it is about infinitive vs. finite verb forms.

Comment: Right. This is a case of [conjunction reduction](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/51955/15299), removing repeated material from _A well thought-out system can streamline operation, **and a well thought-out system can**  improve work process, **and a well thought-out system can** reduce data redundancy..._

Answer (score -1):

A well thought-out **system** *streamlines* operation, *improves* work process, *reduces* data redundancy.....

It seems you understand what the subject is and what the active verbs are.

When you add a modal verb its principal verb is always in its infinitive form, and no suffixes are added.
So the first option is the correct one.

Though this question is more suited to English learners.