# Does consider change all verbs to gerund until the end of the sentence?

Tags: gerunds

Take this sentence as an example:

> You may want to consider placing the money in a more conservative
> portfolio and move on with life.

The expression "move on with life" is fine by itself, but "moving on with life" brings in ample amount of Google results as well. But shouldn't "move" be in gerund form much like "placing"? So:

> You may want to consider placing the money in a more conservative
> portfolio and **moving** on with life.

When in doubt, I like to shorten the sentence to get rid of the noise, to something that is still structurally the same. Such as

> You may want to consider burning the money and **moving** on with life.

Here the two verbs are much closer and I wouldn't even consider writing *move*.

Comment: No: the coordination consists of the two clauses "to consider placing the money in a more conservative portfolio" and  "move on with life", both of which are infinitivals.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with "You may want to [consider burning the money] and [move on with life].

Comment: Either gerunds or infinitives will work after _consider_. But they hafta be the same on both sides of the conjunction for [Conjunction Reduction](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/524673/15299) to produce grammatical output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding a bit on the other answer:

> You may want to consider placing the money in a more conservative portfolio and move on with life.

This sentence is fine. The conjunction "and" is here interpreted as joining "consider placing the money in a more conservative portfolio" and "move on with life."

> You may want to consider placing the money in a more conservative portfolio and moving on with life.

This sentence is also fine. The conjunction "and" is here interpreted as joining "placing the money in a more conservative portfolio" and "moving on with life."

The second sentence certainly sounds better, and it avoids breaking the nonexistent rule against split infinitives, but both are correct, with (subtly) different meanings. To see the difference, it may help to rephrase them slightly:

> 1. You may want **to** consider placing the money in a more conservative portfolio **and to** move on with life.
> 2. You may want to consider **both** placing the money in a more conservative portfolio **and** moving on with life.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a matter of "to the end of the sentence": it's a matter of the (semantic) scope of "consider".

In your original example, both are possible, but they have logically different structures, though little practical difference in meaning.

*Moving on* is within the scope of "consider": something else you may want to consider.

*Move on* is outside the range of "consider", but still within the range of "want": something else you may want to do (separately from considering).