# Can conjunction reduction be applied with "so"?

Tags: grammar, conjunctions, conjunction-reduction

The following examples of [conjunction reduction](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51930/i-verb-and-am-rest-of-sentence/51955#51955) sound wrong to me; are they grammatically correct?

> The meat is red, so is raw. [The meat is red, so it is raw.]

> The fish is pink, so is a salmon. [The fish is pink, so it is a salmon.]

Maybe my discomfort comes from the proximity with this other "so" (adverb) construction:

> The meat is red, so is the wine.

> The fish is pink, so is the rose.

Comment: Your first two examples are not correct. _So_ here means _therefore_. In the second pair of sentences, _so is X_ means _X is the same_.

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks, that's what I thought. But then what is the rule? Conjunction reduction doesn't apply to "so"?

Comment: You _could_ say "The meat is red, _and_ so is raw", though it wouldn't be very idiomatic. Presumably we don't use _so is_ on its own in this context because it could be confused with the other sense of _so is_.